# OKTA sso for Salesforce CanvasApp

Tags: salesforce, okta, okta-api

We are working on canvasAPP in salesforce and that requires single sign on between salesforce and External Application(External java Web application). Basically we are going to have a tab/button in salesforce for Ext Application that should automatically login at the backend and load the external application inside the salesforce.

What we are thinking is to Create an Identity User in OKTA and link the identity user  to the admin user in salesforce by using the federation ID. As soon the user clicks the button  it should be redirected to the  identity provider and then back to the service provider and it’ll be automatically logged in to the service provider as the administrator.

Is it something doable with OKTA.?? Does any have done something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this most notably, via a Service Provider Initiated SAML Assertion. A good place to get started is with the developer docs.

http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/spring_security_saml.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, we are not using “Spring Security”, but a different SAML library.